# Is it good to use async void to run a non-cpu consumming task after a certain delay?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Here is my code :

```
class StateManager
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, bool> _states = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, bool>();

    public void SetState(int id, bool state)
    {
        _states[id] = state;

        if (!state)
            RemoveLately(id);
    }

    private async void RemoveLately(int id)
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000).ConfigureAwait(false);
        _states.TryRemove(id, out _);

    }
}
```

My goal is to remove an item after a certain lapse of time. I do not want to use Task.Run  for `RemoveLately` as it may be called thousands times.
What could be the drawbacks of such practice if any ?

Comment: Change `void` to `Task`.

Comment: `async void` is only meant for event handlers. `RemoveLately` isn't an event handler. The drawbacks are big and well documented. `async void` methods can't be awaited or monitored. If `StateManager` is disposed the method will still run and try to call `_states.TryRemove()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My goal is to remove an item after a certain lapse of time.

Then why not use a cache?

> Is it good to use async void?

The guideline for `async void` is to [avoid `async void` unless you're implementing an event handler (or something that is logically like an event handler)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). So the real question here is: is `RemoveLately` logically an "event handler"? I can see an argument where it could be considered one; specifically, `TryRemove` is called in response to a timer "event" (`Task.Delay`). So I wouldn't absolutely say that `async void` is wrong here, but it does come with drawbacks.

> What could be the drawbacks of such practice if any?

There is one primary problem with `async void` methods: other code cannot know when that method is complete.

This primary problem is manifested in several ways:

- Your code cannot catch or handle exceptions from `RemoveLately`. Since there is no way to observe completion for `async void` methods, there is also no way to observe exceptions. So `async void` methods just raise any exceptions directly on their original `SynchronizationContext`. In most cases, this means exceptions in `async void` methods will crash the application.
- `async void` methods are difficult to test. This is because the unit testing code cannot know when the `async void` method has completed.
- Your code cannot know when it is safe to shut down (where the scope of "shut down" can mean "exit the program", or "dispose `StateManager`", or anything in-between). This is because your code cannot know whether there may be `async void` work still in progress. In this particular case where `RemoveLately` is just removing an object from a cache, this should be fine to ignore, but in the general case `async void` means the application never knows when it's "done".

Answer (score 0):

No async void is (almost) always bad (s. [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)).
As stated by Stephen in his Article and his answer here, there are some reasons to have async void Methods (namely async Eventhandlers that never have any other "return" value than void). The reasons why you should change to async Task and why they are better is explained by Stephen in his answer.

That is why I would propose that your method should look like this:

```
private async Task RemoveLately(int id)
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000).ConfigureAwait(false);
        _states.TryRemove(id, out _);

    }
```

As a small remark (if I may): If you are unsure what to choose and/or you are able to choose either `Task` (or `Task<T>`) or `async void` then try to use `Task` because in almost every case (except event handling) you are better of with `Task` than with `async void`.